# scala typemimatch _$1 found instead of required Type

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, existential-type

I am using scala 2.11.
I have question on the scala generic types and pattern matching.

In the class `MyImpl.example()`, compiler is unhappy saying `type mismatch, Required: _$1, Found: X[_ <: A]`

```
trait A

class B extends A

class C extends A

trait Foo[T <: A] {
  def foo(arg: T): Unit
}

class Bar extends Foo[B] {
  override def foo(arg: B): Unit = print("Bar")
}

class Car extends Foo[C] {
  override def foo(arg: C): Unit = print("Car")
}


class MyImpl {

  def getA(): A = {
    new B()
  }

  def example(): Unit = {
    getFoo("1").foo(getA())
  }

  def getFoo(something: String): Foo[_ <: A] = {
    //return either
    something match {
      case "1" => new Bar()
      case "2" => new Car()
    }
  }
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    new MyImpl().example()
  }
}
```

Note: getFoo("1") is more dynaminc in my real case, here is just an example.

I kind of understand this, compiler is unable to predict on which pair of the 2 implementation the method is invoked.

I am able to work around this, if I change the implementation of `MyImpl.example()` to

```
def example(): Unit = {
    (getFoo("1"), getA()) match {
      case (i: Bar, j: B) => i.foo(j)
      case (i: Car, j: C) => i.foo(j)
    }
  }
```

I am not really happy with this as I am just repeating `i.foo(j)`

Any scala functional style writing much cleaner code?

Comment: Something is wrong with your setting. Your fixed `example` fails at runtime: `MatchError` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/wSrJmmUXRV2iHLgvriX4YA/4 And your original `example` doesn't compile even with casting https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/wSrJmmUXRV2iHLgvriX4YA/2 You can't apply `(??? : Bar).foo(??? : Z)`, only `(??? : Bar).foo(??? : B)`.

Comment: If you fix your setting then your question can be like this is desired runtime behavior, how to convince the compiler. But currently it's not clear what desired runtime behavior is.

Comment: My bad! I have corrected and simplified the example, althouth it's not this simple in the actual case, however the example depicts the problem. Thanks

Comment: Not really, since there is no way to know at compile time that the runtime class of `getA` will correspond with the type parameter of the underlying runtime class of `getFoo` _(and there may even be erasure problems)_. Your problem is basically asking the compiler to predict the future.

Comment: @Betta Thanks for fixing your question. What is desired runtime behavior for `getFoo("1")` and  `getA` producing `new C` (or vice versa `getFoo("2")` and `new B`)? `ClassCastException`, `MatchError`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want something like

```
(getFoo("1"), getA()) match {
  case (i: Foo[t], j: t) => i.foo(j) // doesn't compile, not found: type t
}
```

or

```
(getFoo("1"), getA()) match {
  case (i: Foo[t], j: Id[t]) => i.foo(j) // doesn't compile, t is already defined as type t
}

type Id[T] = T
```

You can remove code duplication in

```
def example(): Unit = {                    // (*)
  (getFoo("1"), getA()) match {
    case (i: Bar, j: B) => i.foo(j)
    case (i: Car, j: C) => i.foo(j)
  }
}
```

(or fix compilation of `getFoo("1").foo(getA())`)

with **nested** pattern matching

```
getFoo("1") match {
  case i => getA() match {
    case j: i._T => i.foo(j)
  }
}
```

if you add type member `_T`

```
trait Foo[T <: A] {
  type _T = T
  def foo(arg: T): Unit
}
```

For `getFoo("1")` and `getA` producing `new B` this prints `Bar`,  vice versa for `getFoo("2")` and `new C` this prints `Car`, for other combinations this throws `ClassCastException` similarly to (*).

Please notice that this can't be rewritten as just a variable declaration and single pattern matching

```
val i = getFoo("1")
getA() match {
  case j: i._T => i.foo(j)
}
//type mismatch;
// found   : j.type (with underlying type i._T)
// required: _$1
```

because for nested pattern matching the types are inferred correctly (`i: Foo[t]`, `j: t`) but for `val i` the type is existential (`i: Foo[_]` aka `i: Foo[_$1]` after [skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form), `j: _$1`).

Comment: This would work for now, although `MatchError` is desired. Is it not possible to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: @Betta The thing is that my nested matching is just a way to convince the compiler, it just hides casting and isn't better than just `type T <: A; getFoo("1").asInstanceOf[Foo[T]].foo(getA().asInstanceOf[T])`. I can imagine `try ... catch { case _: ClassCastException => throw new MatchError() }`. I can automate with a macro the pattern matching like in your fixed `example` but this would be an overkill.